# Two errors with FIPS when trying to deploy to device from Xcode 11.1 after upgrading to MacOS Catalina 10.15

Tags: ios, xcode, blackberry, macos-catalina, good-dynamics

I use Blackberry Dynamics SDK in my app and after upgrading to the new MacOS 10.15 Catalina I have issues deploying to a physical device. I cleaned the build folder, cleared the cache, cleared derived data, uninstalled/reinstalled all pods, but I still get the following error:

```
FINGERTYPE is [path]/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/../bin/fips_standalone_sha1
CANISTER_O is [path]/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/../lib/fipscanister.o
[path]/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/gd_fipsld: line 219: [path]/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/../bin/fips_standalone_sha1: Bad CPU type in executable
1d0
< HMAC-SHA1(fipscanister.o)= [key]
[path]/FIPS_module/arm64.sdk/bin/../lib/fipscanister.o fingerprint mismatch
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

It builds and deploys fine to a simulator as well as if deployed in an earlier version of MacOS. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: BlackBerry had over a year of warning that this was going to break...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While compiling a Blackberry Dynamics app the command `fips_standalone_sha1` is called. The `fips_standalone_sha1` binary in the Blackberry Dynamics framework is a 32-bit binary. That is not going to work on Catalina.

Mojave still supported 32 bit applications, but it was deprecated, in Catalina 32-bit applications won't run anymore.

You can use a Mojave system, or wait for an update of Blackberry Dynamics SDK that supports Catalina.

EDIT: Blackberry Dynamics has been updated, make sure you are using the latest version

Comment: Hi Marcel,
As suggested I have updated BB Dynamics SDK from 6.1 to 7.1 and trying to run the app on Mac Catalina with Xcode 11.1. 
Still I am getting this error - '/Users/username/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/armv7.sdk/bin/gd_fipsld' (No such file or directory). Could you please help here?

Comment: If you check in the build settings you can see that the path is created with your current architecture: FIPS_PACKAGE=$(CURRENT_ARCH).sdk LDPLUSPLUS=$(HOME)/Library/Application Support/BlackBerry/Good.platform/iOS/FIPS_module/$FIPS_PACKAGE/bin/gd_fipsld, In the directory you will now only find a arm64.sdk directory, so I think you need to check your build architectures

Answer (score 0):

Blackberry Dynamics SDK for iOS 6.2 and above supports MacOS Catalina.
I had the same problem but could solve it by updating the SDK.